# Two Neutral Wires on Light Switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, grounding, neutral

I want to install an in-wall lighting timer for my front outdoor lights, replacing an existing light switch. I turned off the breaker to the switch I wish to replace and I've determined which black wire is the line (blue tape in image).

The timer switch installation calls for using a single neutral wire, but I have two separate neutral wires on the existing light switch. As well, no ground wire is installed on the current switch; I do however see some ground wires twisted together in the same box behind the other switch.

To install the timer switch, do I wire-nut both neutral wires together with a pigtail to the timer switch neutral screw and pigtail a ground to the current ground-wire group?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking more squarely into the back of the box please?  Also, is this the only switch that controls said outdoor lights (I KDI), and what make and model is your timer?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've discovered that this is a 4-way switch after receiving replies to the same query in another forum. What I am now wondering is can any of the 3 switches on the 4-way circuit be replaced with the timer switch?

Comment: The other replies are indeed correct that this is a 4-way switch.  What make/model is your timer?

Comment: myTouchSmart In-wall Lighting Timer
Item #192773Model #41431-T1

Comment: https://www.lowes.com/pd/myTouchSmart-myTouchSmart-24Hr-In-Wall-Digital-Timer-with-On-Off-Door/5001067087

Comment: Are you OK with having to open up the wall a bit? Also, can you post photos of the insides of the boxes at the other switch locations please?

Comment: Just a tip for future work, should not have that much bare copper wire showing at switches/outlets.  Just want enough for the screw to cover.

Comment: Your existing switch has exactly zero neutral wires connected to it, because 'dumb' switches do not use or switch neutral. Do not just look at a white wire and assume it's neutral - it often is not, particularly when switch loops and 3/4-way switch circuits are involved. Look in the back of the box for that bundle of white wires all connected together - that's where you can probably get a neutral for your new switch (if you figure out how to use it in your 3/4-way circuit).

Comment: "Are you OK with having to open up the wall a bit? Also, can you post photos of the insides of the boxes at the other switch locations please?" I will have to take off some 4 slot switch covers and link some pictures tonight. As far as opening the wall...I hope that is not necessary! Thanks for the help - I'll post some pics soon.

Comment: One last question: how many watts of outdoor lighting are you seeking to control here?

Comment: "One last question: how many watts of outdoor lighting are you seeking to control here? " 180 total 3x60